# Creating a table from a query result in bigquery using node.js

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to do as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result

However I'm using the node.js client libraries for which there is no documentation there. Possibly this is not supported by the node.js client libraries, or possibly it's not yet documented for node.js.

**===Alternative solution===**

An alterative solution, as suggested by @ElliottBrossard is to use the create table statement documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

as follows

```
bigQuery.query({
  query: 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<project_name>.<dataset_name>.<output_table_name>` AS SELECT * FROM `<project_name>.<dataset_name>.<input_table_name>*`',
  useLegacySql: false, // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
})
```

Comment: Did you see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement?

Comment: No I hadn't. That seems like it might work. Thanks

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted. Very much appreciated. @ElliottBrossard

Comment: Great! Consider posting a snippet of the code that you used as an answer to help anyone with the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution proffered in the question, there is native support for writing query results to a table.  [`BigQuery.createQueryjob`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createQueryJob) will write results to a new table.  The name of the table is specified in the `destination` property of the options object.

An [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#permanent-table) is online as part of the documentation.